# How to get all classname from previous element's NodeList?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, classname

I want to add some event listener to every button which placed after some block of element. This button intended to return all element classes from previous block of element if clicked.

I found the script to get classes from NodeList here, https://gist.github.com/cssence/41c8279810b1db71670d.js

```
for (var k = 0; k < trigger.length; k++) {
  trigger[k].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    nav.classList.toggle('hidden');
    (function listAllUsedClassNames() {
      var classNames = {};
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.previousElementSibling.querySelectorAll("*"), function(element) {
        if (typeof element.className === "string") {
          element.className.split(" ").forEach(function(className) {
            if (className) {
              classNames[className] = true;
            }
          });
        };
      });
      return Object.keys(classNames);
    }());
  }, false);
}
```

I want some array contains all classes of previous block returned after the button clicked. It would be better if the result is unique and doesn't have any duplicated item.

Comment: You want class of nested elements of the previous element too?

Comment: are there any solution so the result is unique, not duplicated. I want to use the array to get some element style here.

Comment: You should detail requirements at the time when question is posted.

Comment: Yes, I want class of nested elements of the previous element. As deep as the DOM tree exist. But without duplicate value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the previous Element, use `previousElementSibling`. Iterate over the `childNodes` to get the classes of element using `classList`.

```js
let classes = [];
document.querySelectorAll('button')
  .forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      classes = [];
      const prev = this.previousElementSibling;
      classes.push(...prev.classList);
      prev.childNodes.forEach(child => {
        if(child.nodeType == 3) return; // Ignore text node
        classes.push(...child.classList);
      })
      console.log(classes);
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <p class="childOfFirst">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Repudiandae totam dicta libero vero dolore aperiam consectetur. Non veritatis quo praesentium!</p>
</div>
<button>Button1</button>
<div class="second">
  <p class="childOfSecond">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, hic.</p>
</div>
<button>Button2</button>
```

For multiple nesting, use `recursion`

```js
let classes = [];

document.querySelectorAll('button')
    .forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            classes = [];
            const prev = this.previousElementSibling;
            if(prev.children.length > 0) {
                const output = getNestedClasses([...prev.children]);
                classes.push(...prev.classList, ...output);
                console.log('With Duplicates', classes);
                const uniqueClassList = removeDuplicateClasses(classes)
                console.log('Without Duplicates', uniqueClassList);
            }
        });
    });

function getNestedClasses(childrens) {
    return childrens.reduce((accu, ele) => {
        if(ele.children.length > 0) {
            accu.push(...ele.classList);
            return accu.concat(getNestedClasses([...ele.children]));
        } else {
            return accu.concat([...ele.classList]);
        }
    }, []);
}

function removeDuplicateClasses(classArr) {
    return Object.keys(classArr.reduce((accu, name) => {
        accu[name] += (accu[name] || 0);
        return accu;
    }, {}));
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    <p class="firstChild">First Child
        <span class="firstGrandChild">First Grand Child</span>
        <span class="secondGrandChild">Second Grand Child</span>
    </p>    
    <p class="secondChild duplicate">Second Child</p>
    <p class="duplicate"></p>
    <p class="thirdChild">Third Child</p>
</div>
<button>Button1</button>
```

Comment: Hi, @randomSoul, after I test them in deep DOM tree as each parent had three or four child and each child has their own child. There is an error: Uncaught TypeError: classes.push is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: @ian - First code snippet was for one level nesting if there are more than one nesting, use recursion. I have added code for multiple nesting as well to remove the duplicate classes. See edit.